# Call Apex REST service from JS on same org VF page - how to get instanceUrl and authToken?

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, oauth

I have an Apex class implementing a simple REST GET method

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myrest/*') 
global class MyResService {

   @HttpGet
   global static CustomObject__c doGet() {
     ..
   }
}
```

and a Visualforce page including Javascript code that requests this service's (JSON result)

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery_min_js}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
   $j = jQuery.noConflict();
   $j.ajax({
    url: '{!InstanceUrl}/services/apexrest/myrest',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function() { console.log(error); },
    success: function() { alert('hello!'); },
    beforeSend: setHeader
   });

   function setHeader(xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth {!OAuthToken}");
   }

 ...
```

My question now is how to I get the {!OAuthToken} and {!InstanceUrl}? I have seen quite complex solutions that seem to be required when calling ANOTHER ORG's service. I need the simple ONE ORG solution ;).

Comment: Why not simple static Apex method exposed as webservice and accessed with AJAX toolkit? Or if it's on VF page - read about @RemoteAction?

Comment: Yes I am also wondering why JavaScript Remoting is not a better solution for you here? Not that, unlike REST API, it will not count against the orgs 24hr rolling API limit.

Comment: See above comments, are `{!$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_270}` and `{!$Api.Session_ID}` any good?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution provided by Ivo Rocha is nice but too complex for my case. When I thought deeper about my problem I found out that Apex REST services are not the best solution when you just need to pass their result to a VF page in the same org.

**The solution is: Use Javascript Remoting instead!**

Answer (score 3):

I've already implemented a solution that looked like this. I've used the [forceTK](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/blob/master/forcetk.js) javascript plugin. Download it and use it as a static resource.

Then create a function like this:

```
<script>
    var client = new forcetk.Client();
    client.yourAjaxNewFunction = function(your_params){
        var url = this.instanceUrl + '/services/apexrest/yourRest';
        $j.ajax({
            async: this.asyncAjax,
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            error: function() { console.log(error); },
            success: function() { alert('hello!'); },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                if (this.proxyUrl !== null) {
                     xhr.setRequestHeader('SalesforceProxy-Endpoint', url);
                }
                xhr.setRequestHeader(this.authzHeader, "OAuth " + this.sessionId);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-User-Agent', 'salesforce-toolkit-rest-javascript/' + that.apiVersion);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('param1', param1Value);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('param2', param2Value);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

To use it just call the new "yourAjaxNewFunction" client method

```
<script>
  client.yourAjaxNewFunction(your_params);
</script>
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: I get a "parsererror" when I make a call using the above method. I confirmed that there is nothing wrong with the service by testing it from workbench.developerforce.com. It only errs out when I access it via an ajax call. Any ideas?