# Access REST API in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, rest-api

In a Visualforce page, how can I invoke a custom REST API that is built in Salesforce (this org is same org in which the VF is in). This is how I access the REST API in workbench using REST Explorer so I know it works correctly.

/services/apexrest/checkEntitlement?contract=KA03MC8919

In my VF page, there is a jQuery function from where I need to call the API and this is how am doing it

```
    $j.ajax({
      url: "/services/apexrest/checkEntitlement?contract=KA03MC8919"
    }).done(function (data){
      console.log(data);
    });
```

When I check the status of the call, it gives as Canceled. Can you tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try looking at the below blog post http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/10/not-calling-the-rest-api-from-javascript-in-visualforce-pages.html

Comment: Why use Ajax? Why not just use RemoteAccess - it's much easier.

Comment: @metadaddy, its a good point but I was just curious why VF cant call REST API.

Comment: I am closing this post and going to collaborate on this post - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9792/call-apex-rest-service-from-js-on-same-org-vf-page-how-to-get-instanceurl-and